# How to hide the JScrollBars in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I can't seem to find an answer to this on stackoverflow or at the javadoc site. It's probably very trivial. Could someone help?

Comment: The question is why do you want to do this. If you want to hide the scrollbars, then why add the component to a scrollpane?

Comment: @camickr, in my case I had two JTextAreas inside different JScrollPanes.  When the main one is scrolled, I wanted the other to follow along with an AdjustmentListener but I didn't want the subordinate one to control the flow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think with setHorizontalScrollBarpolicy() you can set scrollbar apperance means when you want to display your scrollbar like JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS displays vertical scrollbar always and so on.. This may help you.

```
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(lista);
        jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        jsp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(...) 
scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added it I would assume you don't want it to show when the ContentPane size is still in range so the below code would make the ScrollBar to only show when the content of the ContentPane grows beyond the container size..

```
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(container, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEEDED);
```

For me I only prefer the vertical so if you're like me you should use the code below:

```
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(container, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```